# Django: how to control time format in DataTable?

Tags: django, datatable

I use DataTable in a Django project

context pass to my template : Heures.objects.all()

my problem concern heu_dat field that is display as 1 pm where 13:00:36.227396 is stored in my database

I would like to display heu_dat like 13:00:36 (french format)

models.py

```
class Heures(models.Model):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    heu_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.ForeignKey(Jours, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    heu_dat = models.TimeField("Heure du pointage", null=True, blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
    heu_cod = models.IntegerField("Code employé", null=True, blank=True)    
    heu_com = models.CharField("Commentaires", max_length = 150, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: The database has no "format". It simply stores a date time. It is the "interface" of the database that uses a certain format. But that is not relevant at all. You simply need to render it properly in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output in the template like this:

```
{{ your_time|time:'H:i:s' }}
```

H for hour, i for minutes and s for seconds, you can see more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date).